# Find X and Y coordinates of each picture in a table cell

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a matching game. I've created a left and right td with elements that are to be matched. The middle td contains a canvas.

When there is a correct match, I would like to draw lines on the canvas to match the items. To do that, I require the coordinates of each picture then draw it accordingly in the canvas. The following is an illustration

[image]

Red represents the td
Green represents the line I wish to draw

There isn't much problem with the x coordinate because I just take the width(300px)of the canvas(draw from 0 to 300) but it's the y coordinate which is the problem.

The idea I have is

1. Find y coordinate of picture1
2. Add half the px of the picture1 so that it's in the 'center' of the picture1
3. Do the same for picture2
4. Draw line using those coordinates

Is there any way to find the y coordinate of the picture within the table because it matches equally with the y coordinate of the canvas?

**HTML**

```
<table class="first">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul class="firstleft"></ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul class="firstright"></ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
table ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
ctx.lineWidth = 6;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#333";
/* Drawing part using an example*/
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100, 250);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(150, 100, 350, 100, 400, 250);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: You should name your game "Pear Match", get it? ;D

Comment: HAHA. Yea I named that originally. I wonder why I changed it :D

Comment: If you can get the size of all of the images (or all of the cells) you can calculate the y coordinate by knowing which cell you're in. Example: if cell A is 100px high, and cell B underneath is 100px, assuming the top of the canvas is the same as the top of the table, the y coordinate for cell B would be (A + B) - (B/2), or 150px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an overly verbose, not streamlined block of code to enforce clarity. It also just does the left side, but obviously you would change the functions to take the names and positions arrays as arguments, to support left and right, etc.

```
var yPositionForMiddleOfEachImage = [];
var myImageNames = ['leftImage0', 'leftImage1', 'leftImage2']; //etc

var calculateYValuesForLeftSide = function () {
  var thisImagesHeight = 0, halfOfImageHeight = 0, totalOfAllPreviousImagesHeight = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myImageNames.length; i++) {
    thisImagesHeight = document.getElementById(myImageNames[i]).clientHeight;
    halfOfImageHeight = thisImagesHeight / 2;

    yPositionForMiddleOfEachImage.push(totalOfAllPreviousImagesHeight + halfOfImageHeight);
    totalOfAllPreviousImagesHeight += thisImagesHeight;
  }
};

var getCanvasLeftSideYPosition = function (imgPosition) {
  return yPositionForMiddleOfEachImage[imgPosition];
};
```

Comment: overly verbose indeed